# How to display(set) only particular items in drop-down?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop-down here. I've made it multi-select.
I am populating this drop-down as shown in code.

```
<td class="border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0 align-middle form-group">
  @{
     SelectList newSelectList = new SelectList((from s in Model.UserMasterList.ToList()                                                                   
     select new
     {
       userId = s.userId,
       userName =  (s.userFirstName +' '+  s.userLastName)
     }).Distinct(), "userId","userName",
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.JobConstructionManagerId.ToString()) ? 0 : item.JobConstructionManagerId);           
}

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.JobConstructionManagerId, (SelectList)newSelectList, new { @class = "form-control js-select js-noFilter hidden DDConstructionManager", size = "2", @value = 0, Id = "JobConstructionManager" + t, @OnChange = "fill(" + t + ")" })
</td>
```

I want to show only those items which was provided though model not all items from drop-down, please refer following image.

[image]

The values are setting to drop-down very well but I want to show only these values not others. If possible hiding other items which are not selected.

Comment: So which are the provided items through the model and where they are?

Comment: its **item.JobConstructionManagerId** ..values send from controller though model @er-mfahhgk

Comment: that means you have to only show `Standard User 1` in your drop down? If yes then only one item is remaining in your drop down and what you are going to do with only one item in drop down?

Comment: in this case single item is selected there can be a possibility of 2 or more items get selected @er-mfahhgk

Comment: if there are 2 items then which one item will be hold by `model => item.JobConstructionManagerId` because i think its hold only single item id

Comment: both which are selected @er-mfahhgk

Comment: means your `item.JobConstructionManagerId` can hold list of Id's, right?

Comment: yes @er-mfahhgk

Comment: I added answer try it and let me know.

Comment: glad to see my answer was help you :) vote up if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter you select list items from list of `JobConstructionManagerId` like

```
(from s in Model.UserMasterList.ToList()                                                                   
 select new
 {
      userId = s.userId,
      userName =  (s.userFirstName +' '+  s.userLastName)
 })
 .Where(x => item.JobConstructionManagerId.Contains(x.userId))
 .Distinct()
```